# Pass Jenkins build number to Protractor for SauceLabs

Tags: jenkins, protractor, cucumberjs

I am running protractor test cases through Jenkins, and using SauceLabs as execution environment. I am using Protractor-Cucumber-Framework. I want to pass build number from Jenkins so that I can pass same to SauceLabs to organize my test execution results.

I tried params as mentioned in this post
https://moduscreate.com/blog/protractor_parameters_adding_flexibility_automation_tests/

in Config.js

```
 params: {
         buildNumber:'xyz'
     }
```

for running protractor :

```
protractor config/config.js --parameters.buildNumber= 1.1 --disableChecks"
```

using :

```
browser.params.buildNumber
```

This gives buildnumber =xyz and not 1.1

Could you please help me here

Update:
Sorry forgot to mention that I am using `browser.params.buildNumber` in after hook of `cucumberjs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use pattern: `--params.xxx` in cmd line, rather than `--parameters.xxx`.

In your case, should be: `protractor config/config.js --params.buildNumber=1.1 --disableChecks`

Note: Don't insert blank space around the `=`, like `--params.name = value`, or `--params.name= value`.

If the parameter value has blank space, you should use double quote to wrapper it, like `--params.name="I like to xxx"`